# Insert in stl set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I need to keep a collection of integers in a priority_queue. However I need to be able to remove one of these integers even if it's not the first element of my container. I couldn't use std::priority_queue. 
I chose to use a set which would keep the integers sorted **based on a custom comparator**.

```
class Comparator
{
    vector<double>& cmp;
    public:
    Comparator(vector<double>& a_cmp) : cmp(a_cmp) {}
    bool operator() (int i, int j) const {return cmp.at(i) < cmp.at(j);}
};
```

I then used the set like this :

```
Comparator comp = Comparator(a_cmp);
set<int, Comparator> my_set (comp);
my_set.insert(index);
```

However it appears that for two integers i and j such as i != j and cmp.at(i) == cmp.at(j), if I try to insert both, only one would be inserted into the set. 
I understand that it is the behaviour of std::set, however I would have prefered if both those integers (which are not equals) would be inserted in the set next to each other. 
In other words I need my custom comparator to be used when sorting the set but not to prevent insertions.
I think it may work when I modify my comparison function for:

```
bool operator() (int i, int j) const {return cmp.at(i) =< cmp.at(j);}
```

However I'm not sure if it's completely correct. Should I use a std::vector with my original comparison function and sort it with std::sort instead?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You're sure you don't want [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)?

Comment: Ah I could, but every integer inserted is unique... So a set should be enough, shouldn't it?
But it is a nicer solution than a manually sorted vector, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll use a multiset then. Thanks all.

Comment: It almost sounds like you'd want a set of sets. The outer set would be ordered by your `cmp`, the inner set by ordinary equality.

Comment: you talk about integers, so why are you using `double`?

Comment: @BlazBratanic sets define equivalence, not equality.

Comment: @TemplateRex I need to keep in the set (or multiset maybe) indexes. And I need to sort those indexes based on an external data structure which is my vector of double. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @BlazBratanic moreover, equivalence is defined as `!cmp(a,b) && !cmp(b, a)`, so if both comparisons are false, then they are equivalent. And `cmp` needs to be a strict weak order (so `<` is OK, but not `<=`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However it appears that for two integers i and j such as i != j and cmp.at(i) == cmp.at(j), if I try to insert both, only one would be inserted into the set. I understand that it is the behaviour of std::set, however I would have prefered if both those integers (which are not equals) would be inserted in the set next to each other.

In your operator(), you could do

```
return (cmp.at(i) < cmp.at(j)) || (!(cmp.at(j) < cmp.at(i)) && (i < j));
```

Which is basically saying that the set will be sorted in ascending order by the value at the index, then by the relative value of the index itself.

Answer (score 1):

Boost has several heap implementations with more features than the one provided with the STL. You can use [boost::heap::fibonacci_heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.html) which has an `erase()` method.

You can find the [complexities of each heap operations here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/heap/data_structures.html#heap.data_structures.data_structure_configuration).